# What does teleporter and armor pack uptime mean?

Tags: terminology, overwatch

Currently you can get end-of-match cards that say

1. "X% teleporter uptime" for Symmetra, and
2. "X% armor pack uptime" for Torbjorn.

What does "uptime" mean in these cards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means for how long of the game you've had a teleporter active or an armor pack on at least one teammate.

Comment: Have a reference for "at least one"? I assumed it was across all teammates. So if I had armor on one person on the team (including myself) for the entire game, that would be 16% uptime. The numbers I've seen for Torbjorn might be too high for that, but I would think it would make sense for Symmetra.

Comment: @DCShannon You might be right, actually. I'll try and do some testing, but it might be hard for me.

Comment: Does armor on yourself count or only on teammates?